# React Native Popup Menu Moving the Options Box

Tags: react-native, react-native-popup-menu

I have a React Native Popup Menu implemented as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import { Icon, Divider } from 'react-native-elements';
import {
  Menu,
  MenuTrigger,
  MenuOptions,
  MenuOption
} from 'react-native-popup-menu';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT } from '../constants';

class PopUpMenu extends Component {
  render() {
    const { menuStyle, menuOptionsStyle, menuTriggerStyle } = styles;

    return (
      <Menu style={menuStyle}>
        <MenuTrigger style={menuTriggerStyle}>
          <Icon
            name="menu"
            color="white"
            size={30}
          />
        </MenuTrigger>
        <MenuOptions style={menuOptionsStyle}>
          <MenuOption>
            <Text>{this.props.user.email}</Text>
          </MenuOption>
          <MenuOption>
            <Divider />
          </MenuOption>
          <MenuOption text="Log Out" onSelect={() => this.signOutUser()} />
        </MenuOptions>
      </Menu>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  menuStyle: {
    marginTop: STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT,
    marginRight: 12
  },
  menuTriggerStyle: {},
  menuOptionsStyle: {}
};
```

Now currently it looks like this closed:

[image: Closed]

And this opened:

[image: Opened]

I would like to have the opened box move down below the trigger button while still keeping the trigger in the same place. How can I accomplish that with styles?

Comment: You will need to do that from within Menu Component I think. You should definitely add which MENU are you using?

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf I don't understand your statement/question.

Comment: Include all your imports and we will be in business

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf there I've added them but I'm not sure how that helps....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can achieve that by passing `optionsContainerStyle` props to MenuOptions component, not style props.

Something like this.

```
<MenuOptions optionsContainerStyle={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
...
</MenuOptions>
```

Comment: Great answer, works for vertical alignment, but doesn't work for horizontal alignment Any ideas?